# mysql fetch array, error-- "Unknown column 'image_name' in 'where clause' where image_name=image name

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create a like/dislike script for an image site. The two scripts (one for the likes, and one for the image displaying) both work separately, but when combining the script, I am receiving this error ""Unknown column 'image_name' in 'where clause'" .  I believe the error is in the $get variable. Here is my script--

```
$query_random_image=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_info ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1")            or die (mysql_error());

        $array_random_image=mysql_fetch_array($query_random_image) or die   (mysql_error());

         $get=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_info WHERE url={$array_random_image['url']}") or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<img src=images/".$array_random_image['url'].">";

        $get_id=mysql_fetch_array($get) or die (mysql_error());


        $get_id_echo=$get_id['id'];

        $rate=$_POST["subject"];

        $get_ratings=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rate WHERE $get_id=image_id") or die(mysql_error());

        $get_ratings_array=mysql_fetch_array($get_ratings) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: You should be using PDO. `ORDER BY RAND()` is the death of MySQL performance. And which query gives you this error?

Comment: well, at the moment after every line of code I have an echo statement which echos numbers counting from 1 up. When I run the script, it stops at 5, which correlates with the          $get=mysql_query("SELECT url FROM image_info WHERE url=    {$array_random_image["url"]}") or die(mysql_error()); So I believe it is where I echo the $array_random_image['url'] to display the image.

Comment: If I use PDO (I hadn't heard of this before) it will just continue to have the same issue, won't it?

Comment: You are right. PDO doesn't fix poor MySQL, but it prevents vulnerabilities that your script doesn't even consider. What is the value of `$array_random_image['url']` right before this `echo 5;`?

Comment: The mysql database has a column named 'url' in a table image_info. So $array_random_image['url'] right before the 5th echo was $get (second line) and before that is the actual query (1st line). It should be pulling a random image name from the column 'url'. is that of any help?  As to the vulnerabilities, I just started coding about a two weeks ago, and haven't implemented any security measures yet. They are to come.

Answer (score 1):

You switch their places in where clause: `$get_id=image_id`

```
$get_ratings=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rate WHERE image_id = $get_id")
```

Comment: I did attempt that, but nothing happened. Same error is displaying.

Comment: After hours of debugging I worked it out. I created another variable which extracts the data from the first mysql_fetch_array before placing it into the second. With the added variable to store the string, it fixed the error. I am not completely sure why, but it helped.